# Mathematica: Evaluation order during numerical optimisation of black box functions

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, black-box, operator-precedence

I am attempting to perform a numerical optimisation of a "black box" function in Mathematica. Schematically it goes like this:

```
NMinimize[{comb[x,y,z], x > 0}, {x,y,z}]
```

where comb[x,y,z] is defined similarly to this:

```
comb[x_,y_,z_] := Module[{},
  Print[x,y,z];
  M = FindMaximum[SkewNormal[a,x,y,z], {a,x}] // First;
  val = f[x,y,z,M];
  Return[val];
];
```

However, all of the minimisation functions I have tried seem to not immediately provide comb[x,y,z] with numerical values, and it ends up trying to evaluate the FindMaximum with symbolic values for x,y,z (which is easily verified because the Print[x,y,z] also evaluates symbolically). The Findmaximum thus fails (FindMaximum::nrnum: The function value blah blah is not a real number) and so the minimisation fails.

How do I fix up the evaluation order so that the sub-functions of comb are evaluated with numerical values?

Comment: Another (more subtle) problem because of symbolic pre-processing in `NMinimize` recently was solved in [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971536/nminimize-eats-all-memory-b-c-of-unnecessary-symbolic-work/6975501#6975501) by Daniel Lichtblau.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks I'll check that out. I have also just noticed that this problem doesn't occur in Mathematica 8 (I was running 7 previously).

Answer (score 5):

Evaluation order for `FindMinimum`, `FindMaximum`, `FindRoot` and `FindFit` is documented on the [tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSymbolicEvaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSymbolicEvaluation.html) Documentation page. I think that something very similar is applicable to the `NMinimize` function. The description is quite lengthy so I will cite here only the proposed solution from that page:

> If your function is such that symbolic evaluation will not keep the
>   function as intended or will be prohibitively slow, you should define
>   your function so that it only evaluates for numerical values of the
>   variables. The simplest way to do this is by defining your function
>   using PatternTest (?), as in f[x_?NumberQ]:=definition.
>
> It may seem that symbolic evaluation just creates a bother since you
>   have to define the function specifically to prevent it. However,
>   without symbolic evaluation, it is hard for Mathematica to take
>   advantage of its unique combination of numerical and symbolic power.
>   Symbolic evaluation means that the commands can consistently take
>   advantage of benefits that come from symbolic analysis, such as
>   algorithm determination, automatic computation of derivatives,
>   automatic optimization and compilation, and structural analysis.

Answer (score 4):

How about changing `comb` to

```
comb[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{}, Print[x, y, z];
 M = FindMaximum[SkewNormal[a, x, y, z], {a, x}] // First;
 val = f[x, y, z, M];
 Return[val];];
```

which causes the definition of `comb` to be evaluated only if its arguments are numbers?

Comment: Nah that doesn't help. My function actually did that already, I just removed those bits for the purposes of asking this question.

Comment: @Ben strange that `Print` would also show symbolic values, since `comb[x,y,z]` with symbolic values would not match the definition I gave. Did you `Clear[comb]` before running this? Maybe it is matching the definition without the `NumericQ` bit.

Comment: @acl This didn't work for me at first, but after clearing it did the trick.